# Javascript filter a big array of objects with the values in a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter a result set returned from an API call. The result set contains an array of strongly typed objects. I'll call this `resultsArray` for the sake of this question.

The values I'm attempting to filter the `resultsArray` with come from *n* criteria found in a second object we'll call `filterObject`. The property names in the `filterObject` are the same as the property names in the `resultsArray`. So, during the iteration process of the `resultsArray` when a matching property is encountered in the two entities, and the value in `resultsArray` matches the value in `filterObject`, that matching row from `resultsArray` is accepted.

Effectively, if no criteria has been entered into the `filterObject` the entire `resultsArray` is returned and displayed. Entering criteria will refine the results to the point where only the records matching all of the criteria entered will be displayed.

Here's what I have in the `filterObject`:

```
const filterObject = {
  usdotnumber: '13',
  mcnumber: null,
  mxnumber: null,
  ffnumber: null,
  vatnumber: '12345',
  nvocc: null,
};
```

In "real life", the values are supplied by a UI form, so all properties could be `null`, which would cause all records returned from the API call to be displayed. However, using the example above, all returned records would be filtered and only those with the `usdotnumber = 13 and vatnumber = 12345` would be displayed.

I've tried to implement various solutions found during web searches, but I can't seem to find one that compares an object to an array of objects for the filtering. Most of them are object to object or array to array. It's enough of a distinction that the errors I'm encountering are things like "key is not indexable" on the `filterObject` which, of course, is correct because it's not an indexable entity. It's only one item with multiple properties and their associated values.

**Edit 1**

In answer to David and Cristian, the error I'm getting is not being able to index on the string.

Here is the specific error, and the code snippet that's generated is posted below.

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'filters'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'filters'.`

```
  processData(carriers: MultiCarrierResponse): void {
    interface filters {
      ffnumber: string | null;
      mcnumber: string | null;
      mxnumber: string | null;
      nvocc: string | null;
      usdotnumber: string | null;
      vatnumber: string | null;
    }

    const filterObject: filters = {
      usdotnumber: '13',
      mcnumber: null,
      mxnumber: null,
      ffnumber: null,
      vatnumber: '12345',
      nvocc: null,
    };

    const filteredResults = carriers?.carriers?.filter((o) =>
      Object.keys(filterObject).every((k) => filterObject[k] === o[k]),
    );

    console.log('The filtered results: ', filteredResults);

    carriers?.carriers?.forEach((element) => {
      this.values.push({
        carrierId: element.carrierId,
        carrierName: element.carrierName,
        carrierStatus: element.carrierStatus,
      });
    });

    console.log('The carriers: ', carriers);
  }
```

**Edit 2**

I'm getting close with this code:

```
  filterByObject(values: any[] | null | undefined, filterObject: any): any {
    const filterKeys = Object.keys(filterObject).filter(
      (key) => filterObject[key] !== null,
    );

    return values?.filter((value: { [x: string]: any }) => {
      return filterKeys.every((key) => filterObject[key] === value[key]);
    });
  }
```

This makes Typescript happy, but I still need to figure out how to include objects from the `resultsArrary` that have a value for/more of the properties in the `filterObject` that are *null*.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. It sounds like you want to `filter` the incoming array, comparing each object in that array to the values in `filterObject`, but it’s not clear what’s preventing you from doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @DaveNewton...what's preventing me from doing so are the errors on the key(s). I'm assuming it's because the result set is an array of objects whereas the filter object is a single object. All of the solutions I've found seem to utilize key(s) in order to perform this type of filtering.

Comment: Right, but I’m asking what *specifically* doesn’t work. Each object passed to the `filter` callback is a single object. In the filter callback you’d compare key/value pairs from `filterObject` against the current object.

Comment: @rcastagna I agree with Dave observation. Why don't you iterate across `filterObject` keys in order to repeat the filter several times?

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

The key error is a Typescript error and occurs because you have defined *only* specific, named properties in the `filters` interface:
`ffnumber`, `mcnumber`, `mxnumber`, `nvocc`, `usdotnumber` and `vatnumbe`. This causes the key type mismatch and disallows you from indexing with a basic `string` type.

You can ignore the error by using

```js
filterObject[k as any]
```

This just causes Typescript to not type check the key indexers.

### Original answer

You could first loop the array, then check against the keys from filterObject.

like so:

```js
const resultsArray = [
  {
    value1: 15,
    value2: 'hello world',
    value3: true,
  },
  {
    value1: 0,
    value2: 'the quick brown fox',
    value3: false,
  },
  {
    value1: 0,
    value2: 'jumps',
    value3: true,
  },
]

function filterByObject(values, filterObject) {
  // create a list of filterObject keys that are not
  // null, this way we can easily skip null checks later
  const filterKeys = Object
    .keys(filterObject)
    .filter(key => filterObject[key] !== null)
    
  return values
    .filter(value => {
      // iterate over each filter key
      return filterKeys
        .every(key => filterObject[key] === value[key])
    })
}

console.log(filterByObject(resultsArray, {
  value1: 0,
}))
console.log(filterByObject(resultsArray, {
  value2: 'hello world',
}))
```

Comment: @jooseba - thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this code doesn't seem to match the resultsArray to the filterObject as it's only capturing the property name in filterObject that is not *null*, not both name and value. I need this to match the value of the property found in the filterObject with the record(s) in the resultsArray that have the corresponding value for the matching property name.

Comment: @rcastagna from the question: "all properties could be null, which would cause all records returned from the API call to be displayed. However, using the example above, all returned records would be filtered and only those with the usdotnumber = 13 and vatnumber = 12345 would be displayed." This makes it seem like null values in the filter object _need_ to be ignored?

Comment: That is correct. Currently, there are six properties to the `filterObject` and up to all six of them could be null. I used your suggestion and with a few things to make typescript happy, I'm mostly there. But, yes, I still need the filtered set to include records from the resultsArray if the corresponding property in the filterObject is null.